# Java Mail API - Encoding problems

Tags: java, api, email, encoding, jakarta-mail

I'm using Java Mail API and I'm trying to send an email through Gmail's SMTP.
How my program works:
java.util.Scanner class is used to get user input - I'm asking user for various parameters to be used in mail sending class; which does the following:

```
Message mailMessage = new MimeMessage(session);
mailMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress("example@example.com"));
mailMessage.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,InternetAddress.parse(mail.getTo()));
mailMessage.setSubject(mail.getSubject());
mailMessage.setText(mail.getMessage());
Transport.send(mailMessage);
```

Everything works as long as I use ASCII symbols/ chars. But whenever I want to use "country-specific" characters - like [õäöü] - I get bunch of weird-looking symbols...

Techniques I've used so far(which don't work for me):

```
setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=UTF-8");
setHeader("Content-Encoding","ISO-8859-9");
setContent(message, "text/plain; charset=iso-8859-2");
```

Note: everything is displayed correctly inside an IDE when System.out.println() is performed to display the message to be sent.

EDIT: e.x. when sent message body is [õäöü]
It's displayed [ä„”?] in Gmail.

EDIT: When `mailMessage.setText(MimeUtility.encodeText(mail.getMessage(), "UTF-8", "Q"));` is used, then the output in Gmail is following:

```
"=?UTF-8?Q?=C3=A4=E2=80=9E=E2=80=9D=EF=BF=BD;=0D=0A?="
```

ANOTHER EDIT: Interestingly, when I do: `mailMessage.setText(strVar + "õäöü", "ISO-8859-1");`
It actually appends "õäöü" nicely in my email (but the first part[strVar] of the string is still full of ?'s and []'s).

Comment: How do you set `strVar`?, and what if you assign `strVar` immediately before that `mailMessate.setText(..)`? Maybe the content you receive from the scanner is not the same as the string that does work.

Comment: I have changed my code a little bit to allow me to send HTML, so my send method is: 
`message.setContent("<h5>[õäöü]</h5><h1>" + strVar + "</h1>", "text/html");`
When I get an mail HTML is parsed correctly, so is "[õäöü]", but `strVar` seems to "come" incorrectly.

I have a class `Input` and `get()` method inside it:

`public String get(){
    /* Scanner declaration here */
    return scanner.nextLine();
}`

And in second class `MailSender` I initialize `strVar` like that: 
`
    /* Input class declaration */
    String strVar = input.get();
`

// Sorry, hard to write code in here :)

Comment: Could you check which actual characters are in the string (and how it compares to the characters in the case that does work)?

Comment: Sure, you can see the output here: [link](http://i50.tinypic.com/9lalmq.jpg)
Output is kind of weird, I run my program in both IDE's (IntelliJ and Netbeans). I used their own console for input [Scanner(System.in)]. Intellij seems to output everything correctly, but Netbeans incorrectly. 
First line(CMD) on picture. It's actually a jar made from Netbeans. It gets subject line right (Netbeans didn't) but body is ok (same in netbeans IDE's console).
"Häid Jõule" means Merry Christmas in Estonian btw :)

Comment: Then the problem is probably not with JavaMail, but with the encoding of the consoles, not sure how to change that though.

Comment: Yes, same thought here. I just migrated from IntelliJ to Netbeans... Oh well - back to IntelliJ then. This issue makes me so angry... I've been trying to fix it since yesterday, I just hoped there would be more than encodings of different IDE's consoles. Feel sad for Netbeans developers :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, my code works just fine, as its supposed to. It was the cmd, that could not handle non-ascii letters. I used a bat file to access a jar. I think I'm just going to make a little GUI then... Thanks everyone for answering.

Comment: Hi all, i have same problem with french characters, i have tried this code:

     MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
     message.setSubject(subject, "UTF-8");
     message.setBody(body, "UTF-8");

Body is being generated correctly but subject i am not getting correctly.Can someone help me

Answer (score 14):

```
    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
    message.setSubject(subject, "UTF-8");
    message.setText(body, "UTF-8");
```

So one has to set the character encoding for both, body and subject.

---

***Addendum because of comment of @bartac***

For the corresponding `MimeBodyPart` do a `setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=UTF-8")`.

Comment: Using `setText` will also set the `Content-Type` header (and if you look through the code you will see that existing `Content-Type` and `Content-Transfer-Encoding` headers are removed after setting any content using `setText` or `setContent`)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel thanks, I will remove the redundant `setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=UTF-8")`.

Comment: `message.setText(body, "text/plain; charset=UTF-8")` or similar haven't worked for me in Windows 10 default Mail application (and sometimes in Outlook) for certain slavic letters. I solved it by using `MimeBodyPart` and setting `setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=UTF-8")` on it.  As for the subject, `message.setSubject(subject, "UTF-8")` worked perfectly for slavic characters (without it, even gmail didn't recognize 'č' character).

Comment: @bartac I have added your solution. Maybe the difference between rich (with a mime part for the plain text) and plain messages.

Answer (score 5):

You should use [`setText(String text, String charset)`](http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/javax/mail/internet/MimeBodyPart.html#setText%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) or [`setText(String text, String charset, String subtype)`](http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/javax/mail/internet/MimeBodyPart.html#setText%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) to set the text body with a specific encoding.

`MimeUtility.encodeText()` is not meant for body text, but only for encoded text in headers (and then only for headers set with `setHeader` or `addHeader`).

Comment: I used this: `mailMessage.setText("input from Scanner here", "ISO-8859-1");`
But nothing changed... What else might be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

The following worked for me:

```
MimeMessage message = ...
message.setSubject(subject, "UTF-8");
message.setContent(body, "text/plain; charset=UTF-8");
```

Where `subject` and `body` are regular String objects with no special treatment (code and user interface use UTF-8).

Answer (score 1):

1- Consider you want to send an email with this string in the body:

```
"Olá João!"
```

2 - As the code is running in the GAE server, this string is interpreted with the default ASCII encoding. To send this email with the correct accented characters, define the String as:

```
String body = "Ol\u00e1 Jo\u00e3o!";
```

The special characters are manually defined with its UTF-8 codes. Search the codes you need in the table http://www.utf8-chartable.de/

3- Convert the string encoding to UTF-8. All the codes manually typed will be now correctly interpreted:

```
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
String encodedSubject = new String (subject.getBytes("UTF-8"),"UTF-8");
String encodedBody = new String (body.getBytes("UTF-8"),"UTF-8");
message.setSubject(encodedSubject, "UTF-8");
message.setText(encodedBody, "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
JavaMailSenderImpl emailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
mailSender.setHost("...");

MimeMessage message = emailSender.createMimeMessage();
message.setSubject("...", "UTF-8");
message.setText("...", "UTF-8");

MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, "UTF-8");
helper.setFrom(from);
helper.setTo(to);

emailSender.send(message);
```

Answer (score 0):

In case if you use HTML messages, try this:

```
Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
message.setContent(htmlText, "text/html; charset=UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

the following charset working to me: `charset=ISO-8859-1`, example:

```
mail.setContent(testMail.getTexto(), "text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1");
```

Comment: why not UTF-8 ?